# How to Convert Javascript Code to C# Code

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a Javascript method. I wrote on C# but it dosen't work.

Javascript Code

```
var __AM = 65521;
    function cc(a) {
        var c = 1, b = 0, d, e;
        for (e = 0; e < a.length; e++) {
            d = a.charCodeAt(e);
            c = (c + d) % __AM;
            b = (b + c) % __AM;
        }
        return b << 16 | c;
    }
```

My written C# Code

```
        private string CC(string a)
    {
        var __AM = 65521;
        int e;
        long d;
        long c = 1, b = 0;
        for (e = 0; e < a.Length; e++)
        {
            var p = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(a[e].ToString());
            d = Convert.ToInt32(p.First());
            c = (c + d) % __AM;
            b = (b + c) % __AM;
        }
        return b.ToString() + c.ToString();
    }
```

JS Test

```
cc("4JipHEz53sU1406413803");
```

Result: 1132332429

C# Test

```
CC("4JipHEz53sU1406413803");
```

Result: 172781421

How Can I get JS value in C#?

Comment: try `byte[] p = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a);` **outside the loop** then just use `d = p[e]`.

Comment: `b.ToString() + c.ToString()` is certainly not equivalent to `b << 16 | c`

Comment: This is Adler-32 checksum algorithm. Perhaps theres a built-in implementation in C#? I don't know.

Comment: It's wrong. Beacuse when it was converted to byte. Just first value of array is available

Comment: There is no reason to conver it to a byte. A string is basically a char[]. Simply cast the char to an int and you'll have the char code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
private string cc(string a)
{
    var __AM = 65521;
    int e;
    long d;
    long c = 1, b = 0;
    for (e = 0; e < a.Length; e++)
    {
        d = (int)a[e];
        c = (c + d) % __AM;
        b = (b + c) % __AM;
    }
    return (b << 16 | c).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Howover, JavaScript always handle strings in UNICODE format, I don't know much about C# but maybe strings are not handled the same way. This code will certainly work for any "a-z 0-9" strings, but how about special characters? It is something that deserves further testing.